# igaph gives me a diameter, but I think the diameter is another one

Tags: graph-theory, networks, social-network, igraph

Given this network:

```r
library(igraph)
set.seed(5)

g <- igraph::graph_from_atlas(100)
E(g)$weight <- round(runif(ecount(g), 0, 10))
#g <- as.directed(g, "acyclic")

plot(g, layout=igraph::layout_nicely(g), edge.label=E(g)$weight)
```

[image]

I compute the diameter:

```
dim <- igraph::diameter(g, weights = NULL)
dim
dimp <- igraph::get_diameter(g)
dimp
```

The diameter equals 20, and the path of the diameter is 2->1->4->6->5.

The diameter is the length of the longest geodesic.

I don't understand why the diameter path is not 2->1->4->5.

It looks longer to me as its length is 9+7+7=23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [geodesic between two nodes of a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) is the length of the *shortest* path between the two nodes. And the shortest path between 2 and 5 goes from 4 *across 6* to 5, not directly from 4 to 5. So the geodesic between 2 and 5 has indeed length 20, not 23.

As you write, the diameter is the longest geodesic between all pairs of nodes. In this case, all other geodesics are shorter than the one between 2 and 5.